# .hover Works, On Click doesn't

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-hover, jquery-on

So this has caused me a lot of headace.
I am making a "pulldown accordion submenu" (for the lack of a better name).
My script works, but only on HOVER. If I try to use .click, .on("click"), .on("click", "li") etc. nothing works. The script only works when using .hover.

NOTE!
It's only the "#TopMenu" that is supposed to have the on click event. The sub-menu ("#accordion") is going to be hover.

Any ideas ?

Working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#accordion li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()

$('#TopMenu li').hover(function() {

        $(this).find('li').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('li').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('li').hide()

});
```

Changing "#TopMenu" to CLICK is NOT WORKING:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#accordion li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()

$('#TopMenu li').on('click', function() {

        $(this).find('li').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('li').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('li').hide()

});
```

I have a working test here: http://jsbin.com/nidazuq/3/embed?html,js,output

I'm going nuts over this, I've searched high and low for a solution. please help.

Comment: can you add HTML mark up as well for demo purposes?

Comment: your "working test" doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID should be unique and single for a page. You used twice in the page. Added fiddle with some changes.

```js
$('#TopMenu li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
$("#TopMenu li ul li > a").hover(function(){
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
#TopMenu li ul, .firstStep ul ul, .firstStep ul{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="TopMenu">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu_heading" rel="menu_heading">CLICK ME</a>
    <ul id="accordion">
      <li> <a href="#" class="history_heading" rel="history_heading">HISTORY</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#" class="geography_heading" rel="geography_heading">GEOGRAPHY</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. I see I was a bit off track here. But what IF I know decide to have the submenu only open on click as well ?? removing hover all together ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using same Ids for multiple elements. This is wrong. You should use class for selection.Change `id='TopMenu'` to `class='TopMenu'` . Second, the 'click' function not triggered with 'li' element. You should listen 'a' element's click function.

```
$('.TopMenu li a').on('click', function() {});
```

I am not familiar with slideDown and slideUp functions but you can continue from there. And don't forget that `$(this)` element refers to `<a href="#" class="menu_heading" rel="menu_heading">CLICK ME</a>` for this click function.